# Getting Mint MATE (Marco?) to put the window-close X in the actual corner, not just near it

Tags: linux-mint, window-manager, mate-desktop

It's nice to be able to fling the mouse up and right, not having to bother with precise targeting, and click.  If your hand's already on the mouse, this is easier than switching back to the keyboard to press Alt+F4 for a quick window close.

E.g. Windows (since at least 95) has made this work, although they at times had very annoying *almost* maximized window defaults that interfered with this quite a bit in some applications.  Nonetheless, actual maximized windows have always capitalized on Fitz' Law in their design this way.

Is there any way to get this behaviour in Linux Mint MATE 18.1?  (Marco is the window manager, it seems.)  As it is, maximized windows will not close with a click in the upper-right corner.  One has to precisely back up a few pixels to activate the X and close it.

Comment: Yeah, this seriously need to be fixed. It's one of "the 5 most easy-to-reach pixels" and it's a shame that it's just wasted.

Answer (score 0):

Mint MATE 1.20.1 on Linux Mint 19 seems to have fixed this.  The odd window (certain Chrome popups, for instance) open annoyingly *almost* full screen, as if they were Internet Explorer in 1999, but actually maximized windows work correctly.

(I know this isn't really an answer for users of 18.1, but it's the current LTS based on Ubuntu Bionic, supported until 2023 instead of 2021.)

Edit: OK, odd.  This was true when I posted it.  A few days later it's no longer the case.  I'm not sure exactly what changed--there weren't many updates installed.  I did plug in an external monitor, but even with that unplugged this is still an issue again.